# Best practice to set up iCloud and Github on two machines

Tags: git, github, visual-studio-code, terminal

So this might be a trivial question but I am new to the whole git thing so I am concerned about how to set myself up properly.

My usual workflow without git: I have two MacBooks, one at work and one at home. I code mostly in Python to solve some equations for my research. I code in VSCode and use the Mac Terminal to compile it. I store my code in a folder on my iCloud Desktop, that way I could seamlessly continue to code from home when I want to finish something. And all changes I made at home are automatically there when I got to the office in the morning.

Now I want to incorporate git / Github in that process. It is my understanding that it is not recommended to pair Github repos and iCloud.

My guess is that best practice would be to set up a Github repo on whatever machine outside of the cloud and whenever I am leaving to commit and push everything to GitHub. And the other machine I could then pull all my changes to continue working on the code locally until I eventually commit/push everything once more to have it available at the office. Do I understand that correctly?

Would it also be best practice to use GitHub Desktop to push/commit or should one use the terminal? Is there something to be gained from using the VSCode Terminal vs. the MacBook Terminal?

Thanks to anybody who can push me in the right direction.

Comment: git has many interfaces, you can just choose the one you like the most (i.e. `git pull` will do the same from Mac's terminal, windows console or the UI of gitHub or gitLab). once you make modifications on your files you "commt" and "push" them , then "pull" them wherever you need them => I'm sure there are many tutorials about this

Comment: Thanks Ivan! I get that, my question is more designed in the direction of what I should be doing to incorporate GitHub in my workflow, e.g. ditching iCloud or not?

Comment: I think you won't need iCloud at all (and you'll be very glad) , gitHub's servers are great and free (if your project is public, if it's not public is still free but with less functionalities)

Answer (score 0):

Without using public repo services, but with personal online storage, the right way to do is configure your online storage folder as a git remote repo, so you can push or pull between local and remote. There's no way to do this on iCloud by now because they don't provide API for this. Dropbox, however, is capable of this. Here is a nice tool to do this: https://github.com/anishathalye/git-remote-dropbox